# How to access attribute of a data frame that has a - operator in it in Python 3?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to access the attribute Job-Label from a dataframe to do the following

```
df.Job-Label.iloc[i] = "something"
```

But this gives an error "can't assign to operator". How can I make this work?

If I write it as

```
df.iloc[i]["Job-Label"] = "something"
```

It creates a copy and no changes are made to the original dataframe.

EDIT:
Here is the snippet of code I am using this in

```
for i in range(len(job_data)):
    x=[]   
    if len(job_data.iloc[i]["Job-Label"])>1:
        for job in job_data.iloc[i]["Job-Label"]:
            if int(job) not in x:
                x.append(int(job))
        job_data.Job-Label.iloc[i] = frozenset(x)
```

Comment: `df.loc[i, "Job-Label"] = "something"`

Comment: Do you want to set "something" in the column 'Job-Label' for all the rows or specific ones ?

Comment: I am running this inside a condition

Comment: `df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc("Job-Label")] = 'something'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to do :

```py
for index in job_data.index.tolist():
    x=[]   
    if len(job_data.loc[index, "Job-Label"])>1:
        for job in job_data.loc[index, "Job-Label"]:
            if int(job) not in x:
                x.append(int(job))
        job_data.loc[index, "Job-Label"] = frozenset(x)
```

Comment: This gives the error
ValueError: Can only index by location with a [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array]

Comment: Well I will need more code from your exemple then. Are you in a for loop ?

Comment: Here I do not know what `i` is. Please edit your question with full code

Comment: which row raise the error ? Which kind of data is stored in "Job" ??

Comment: The error occurs on the first row. Job and Job-labels both contain frozensets of ints and strings. The way I've written in my question works for Job but not Job-Label. Yours however, gives the error for both

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised because python interprets your minus in the name as the minus operator.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you searching for but I would just format the column names to be clean:

```py
import pandas as pd

# create data
data_dict = {}
data_dict['my-col-1'] = ['Apple', 'Orange']
data_dict['my-col-2'] = [1.5, 3.24]
data_dict['weight'] = [12.03, 48.]

# create dataframe from dict
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict)

print(df)

# Print columns names
dict_rename = {}

for col in df.columns.values:
    if '-' in col:
        print("Renaming col %s" % col)
        dict_rename[col] = col.replace("-", "_")

df = df.rename(columns=dict_rename)

print(df)
```

The code output:

```
  my-col-1  my-col-2  weight
0    Apple      1.50   12.03
1   Orange      3.24   48.00
Renaming col my-col-1
Renaming col my-col-2
  my_col_1  my_col_2  weight
0    Apple      1.50   12.03
1   Orange      3.24   48.00
```